# Eigenstates into which a system can be projected after a measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, observables, wavefunction-collapse

I'm currently reading Dirac's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, on page 36, he says:

> Another assumption we make connected to the physical interpretation of the theory is that, if a certain real dynamical variable $\xi$ is measured with the system in a particular state, the states into which the system may jump on account of the measurement are such that the original system is dependent on them.

On what physical basis can we make this assumption and why is it reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon is called the *collapse of the wave function.* It is one of the tenets of the [Copenhagen interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) of quantum mechanics.

The eigenstates $|\xi_i\rangle$ of the $\Xi$ operator form a complete set. From linear algebra we have
$$I=\sum_i|\xi_i\rangle\langle \xi_i|$$
where $I$ is the identity operator. We apply this to the state vector $|\psi\rangle$:
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_i|\xi_i\rangle\langle \xi_i|\psi\rangle$$
We have now expressed the state in terms of the $\Xi$ eigenstates. When we measure $\Xi$ and get $\xi_j$, we *project* the state vector onto the eigenstate using the projection operator $\mathbb{P}_j=|\xi_j\rangle\langle\xi_j|$. So after measurement we get
$$\psi\longrightarrow N\mathbb{P}_j|\psi\rangle=N\langle\xi_j|\psi\rangle|\xi_j\rangle$$
where $N$ is the new normalization constant.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why do they assume this? For instance, we assume wavefunction collapse on basis of a correspondence principle, i.e. if we make two instantaneous ideal measurements, we expect them to be identical, so it has to be projected into an eigenstate, but why do we assume our original state has to be dependent on the set of eigenstates into which it can be projected?

Comment: @user3813284: The eigenstates span the Hilbert space such that the state vector is a *linear combination* of them. They form a *basis*.

Comment: Yes, they form a complete set, but why do we demand in order for a real dynamical variable to be amenable to measurement that its eigenstates (or their corresponding eigenkets) span the Hilbert space? Why does our original state have to be dependant on the set of states into which it can be projected?

Comment: @user3813284: Is this not simple linear algebra? We have a vector space, and we have a complete set of basis vectors. Thus we can expand using the basis vectors.

Comment: @user3813284 *if a certain real dynamical variable ξ  is measured with the system in a particular state, the states into which the system may jump on account of the measurement are such that the original system is dependent on them*, means that if we measure an operator $\hat A$, the system jumps, when measured, into one of the eigenstates of $\hat A$.

Comment: @Sofia Yes, I get this part. It always, after a measurement, has to jump into an eigenstate of the operator, but why does the original state have to be dependant on the set of possible eigenstates into which it may jump? i.e. why does the original ket have to be a linear combination of the possible eignkets into which it may jump? If I'm phrasing my question badly, please tell me, and I'll try to perhaps elaborate further.

Comment: @user3813284: Please see my edit.

Comment: @0celo7 Ok, thank you, this makes sense now, assuming the act of measurement is carried out mathematically using a projection operator, which is reasonable.

Comment: @user3813284 as 0celo7 said, expand the state that the particle has before the measurement, into a superposition of the eigenstates of the operator $\hat A$ that you measure. It's not compulsory that **all** the eigenstates of $\hat A$ appear in the superposition, some eigenstates may have amplitude zero in this superposition. The particle will collapse into one of the states that appear in the superposition. I can't guess what Dirac had in mind, but physically, there is no other possibility. The particle jumps into one of the states that appears in that superposition - none else.

Comment: @user3813284  probably Dirac used a colorful style and meant by states on which the initial state depends, as those states that appear in the superposition.

Answer (score 0):

When you measure an observable over a certain state, any possible outcome lies within the physical spectrum of the observable itself (which can be shown to coincide with the algebraic notion of spectrum for linear operators). So after the measurement has given you a value, say, $\lambda$, any other measurement on the system will give you $\lambda$ again with probability 100%. This is just the probabilistic interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, where the way the expectation value of an observable on a given state is defined as the average over a large enough ensemble of exact copies of the system in the given state. The outcomes must be in the spectrum of the observable, but they way the state is then defined gives you an average over all the possible outcomes. Clearly, once you have collected all the copies of the system in the ensemble that have given you the value $\lambda$, you now know that if you measure the same observable again on this subensemble, you will find $\lambda$ on all of them.

A typical example is that of polarisation. Once you have polarised light, the intensity through a polariser with the same axis will be 100%.